# Trying to get Information from FormData() , cannot send using front-end

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose

When I send data using postman the Title,description and image I am sending goes through.

This is my post array:

```
router.post('/', uploadS3.array('meme',3),(req, res, next)=>{
  // res.json(req.file.location)
  console.log(`req.files =================${req.headers}`);
  // console.log("req.file.location===",req.file.location, "req.body===",req.body);

  const locationURL = req.files.map(item=>item.location);

  //Send image alongside with other form fields
  postModel.create({...req.body,image:locationURL}, (error, returnedDocuments) => {
    if (error) return next(error);
    res.json(returnedDocuments);
  })

})
```

my postman: [image]

When I try to send data using my front end, it does not go to the backend properly, the response I recieve is nothing if I do not include an image, and the title and description is not being passed.... notice that my postModel expects the title and description to be inside of req.body

`postModel.create({...req.body,image:locationURL}`

I am sending the data by appending it to the FormData() object

Just to be clear, setFiles is the setter for file `const [file, setFiles] = useState({ selectedFile: null, loaded: 0 });`

```
const onChangeFile = event => {
  if (maxSelectFile(event) && checkMimeType(event) && checkFileSize(event)) {
    setFiles({
      selectedFile: event.target.files
    });
  }
  console.log(event.target.files)
}

const submitFormHandle = event => {
  const data = new FormData();
  for (let i = 0; i < file.selectedFile.length; i++) {
    data.append("meme", file.selectedFile[i]);
  }
  data.append("title", title);
  data.append("description", description);
  axios
    .post("http://localhost:3200/api/posts/", data)
    .then(res => {
      toast.success('upload success')
    })
    .catch(err => {
      toast.error('upload fail')
    })
}
```

Comment: Is your `meme` array or just the single file name?

Comment: its an array of files, but it works just fine, the issue is I am not getting the title and description

Comment: Means you are getting `meme` on back-end but not `title` and `description`?

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can post axios data by using `FormData` using below approach :

For the field try using `set` on `FormData` object and for image use `append` like this.

Change your code to:

```
data.set("title", title);
data.set("description", description);
```

Kindly let me know if this doesn't work.